# How do I check if each letter is in multiple strings?

Tags: python, arrays, string

I have an array:

```
arr = ['ab', 'ac']
```

I want to check which letters are repeated for **all** items in arr. For the above, 'a' is in both. I would then want to print '1'.

Another example would be:

```
arr = ['abc', 'dca', 'ac']
```

'a' and 'c' are common to all, so I would print 2.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: I would try a dictionary first, but there might be a better way...

Comment: This question looks suspiciously like the most recent Advent of Code problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your entries into sets, then find their intersection:

```py
arr = ['abc', 'dca', 'ac']

set_list = [set(a) for a in arr]
intersection = set.intersection(*set_list)

print(intersection)
print(len(intersection))
```

Output:

```sh
{'c', 'a'}
2
```

References:

- https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp
- https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/set/intersection

Answer (score 7):

You can make a set of the letters of each string, and determine the intersection of all sets:

```
arr = ['abc', 'dca', 'ac']

common = set.intersection(*(set(string) for string in arr))
print(common)
# {'a', 'c'}

print(len(common))
# 2
```

`set.intersection` accepts any number of arguments, we use the `*` to unpack the generator expression yielding the sets.

Answer (score 1):

here i converted the first element of list to to set for using thee intersection and it worked pretty good

```
list_of_sets=['acb', 'ac']
print(len(set(list_of_sets[0]).intersection(*list_of_sets[1:])))
```

Comment: `reduce` is overkill when `set.intersection` can take multiple arguments.

Comment: @FrankYellin i'm not using reduce though

Comment: Oops.  Sorry.  This was meant to go onto the other solution.  Your solution is beautiful!

Answer (score 0):

Using `set` and `reduce` could help out here:

```
from functools import reduce 

print(len(reduce(lambda x,y: set.intersection(set(x),set(y)),arr)))
```

ouputs

```
2
```

Comment: `reduce` is overkill when `set.intersection` can take any number of arguments.